# Explicit description of periodic map $S : HC_{i} \to HC_{i-2}$ for dg and $A_\infty$ algebras

Tags: homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras, a-infinity-algebras, dg-categories, cyclic-homology

Let $A$ some associative unital $k$-algebra, let $HC_*(A)$ is cyclic homology of $A$ and $HH_*(A)$ is hochschild homology of $A$. Then we have Connes exact sequence:
$$ ... \xrightarrow[]{} HH_n(A) \xrightarrow[]{I} HC_n(A) \xrightarrow[]{S} HC_{n-2} (A) \xrightarrow[]{B} HH_{n-1}(A) \xrightarrow[]{I} $$

Moreover there is explicit description of periodic $S$-map, at least when $\operatorname{char} k = 0$ (Loday "Cyclic homology" 2.2.7):

> Let $A$ be a unital $k$-algebra where $k$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $x \in C_n(A)$ be such that $p(x) = \overline{x} \in C_n^\lambda(A)$ is cycle. Then the image of its homology class $[\overline{x}]$ under $S : H_n^\lambda \to H_{n-2}^\lambda(A)$ is the homology class of $\frac{-1}{n(n-1)} \overline{b^{[2]}(x)} \in C_{n-2}^\lambda(A)$.

Where $C_n(A) = A^{\otimes n+1}$ hochschild complex, $C^\lambda_n(A) = C_n(A)/(1-t)$ cyclic complex ($t_n(a_0,...,a_n) = (-1)^n (a_n, a_0,...,a_{n-1})$ is cyclic action on $C_n(A)$), $p : C_n(A) \to C_n(A)/(1-t)$ natural projection, $b^{[2]} = \sum_{0 \leq i<j \leq n} (-1)^{i+j} d_i d_j : C_n \to C_{n-2}$ where $d_i = (a_0,...,a_i,a_{i+1},...,a_n) \mapsto (a_0,...,a_i a_{i+1}, ..., a_n) : C_n \to C_{n-1}$  - simplicial maps.

There is completely full analoges of cyclic and hochschild complexes/homology, analogue of Connes exact seuqence and analogue of explicit descriptions of $B$ and $I$ maps for dg and $A_\infty$ algebras. In fact, explicit description of $B$ and $I$ maps translates to dg and $A_\infty$ algebras pretty directly, because description of $I$ is trivial, and for $B$ we need to know only what is cyclic action on $C_n(A)$. But explicit description of $S$ uses $b^{[2]}$ and $b^{[2]}$ defined in terms of simplicial maps, so I belive that $dg$ and $A_\infty$ analogue of 2.2.7 theorem must include higher multiplications for $A_\infty$ algebras and differential for dg algebras in definition of $b^{[2]}$. Am I right? Does there exist such description?